# Install Apache2.2-common on Ubuntu 16.04 (Raspberry Pi 3)

Tags: 16.04, apt, apache2

I want to install `apache2.2-common` in my Raspberry Pi 3. However, I get this error as show below:

```
ubuntu@ubuntu-standard:~$ sudo apt-get install apache2.2-common
[sudo] password for ubuntu:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Package apache2.2-common is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  apache2

E: Package 'apache2.2-common' has no installation candidate
```

Is there any alternative for `apache2.2-common`? It is same to `apache2` as suggested in error message?

(Note: I use Ubuntu Server Standard 16.04 which can download form [here](https://ubuntu-pi-flavour-maker.org/download/))

Comment: Just a suggestion, but NGINX will run much better on the limited system resources that are available on that hardware.  also, appache2.2 is ancient, try version 2.4.x instead. (if you're going to stick with Apache)